# user activation link fails with 404

Tags: jhipster

I am using Jhipster 4.13.3, successfully running the app with admin and user login.

I registered a new user, got activation link like http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/activate?key=54778803680374675048

Clicking this link gives error page :

```
Your request cannot be processed

Sorry, an error has occurred.
Status: Not Found (Not Found)
Message: Not Found
```

There are no error in the server or client side logs.

After login as admin, I am able to activate this new user, and new user is able to login.

Kindly let me know if any config need to be activated for the link to work.

Comment: You said you are able to activate the user, but the question subject line says you can't activate the user. I'm confused. Can you activate the user or not?

Comment: The link sent through email is not working.  It throws above error in the page.  I am not able to activate and login as a new user.

However, admin is able to activate the user.  After that, new is user is able to login.

Comment: I would like to know if this link is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `application*.yml` the property `jhipster.mail.base-url` should be set to an URL that can be resolved by your end user.

Comment: application-dev.yml has the default setting, base-url: http://127.0.0.1:8080

Pasting this link in the browser gives the same "Your request cannot be processed" error.

The spring boot app is running in 8080.  Does that app need any config change?  I am testing the links from the same machine.

Comment: So everything seems OK. The link matches the route in activate.route.ts. Which authentication type?

Comment: jwt  Any reason why the same error happens even when I go to localhost:8080 ?

Comment: Maybe you did not run a frontend build (http://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/), so in this case the URL would work only on port 9000 (yarn start)

Comment: thanks.  changing base_url to  127.0.0.1:9000 helped.

Comment: Maybe it should be the default or at least we could put a comment in file